# MVC4, Authorize Users based on User Table

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-4, design-patterns

I am having an issue authorizing security on my MVC app. I see many people use AUTHORIZE, but I am not sure if that helps my problem if I am defining custom roles. I have a SQL table of Users and each user is assigned a role for my MVC app (e.g. Admin, Programmer, User), and their username is their windows user name. The windows username is grabbed when they go to my home page so they can only see their stuff and certain functions should be disabled (e.g. the delete ActionLink is disabled on the home page, a drop down box only populates certain value on the edit page). Right now I have a LINQ query checking the repository to see what type of user they are. Also, the admin and programmer should have access to one other special page that the User should not be able to access.

Is the best design pattern to create two separate Index() / Edit() pages or create Html helper classes to disable / enable / hide ActionLinks and other controls? For the special page, how do I implement security to restrict unauthorized users? Thanks.

EDIT: I found a great resource at https://github.com/NickKip/ASPNETCustomMembershipExample

Answer (score 1):

You can use existing `AuthoriseAttribute` but what you should do is implement custom `Principal` class that will use your own roles from DB. In your `Principal` class you will implement IsInRole method:

```
public bool IsInRole(string role)
{
    if(this.Roles == null)
        this.Roles = DependencyResolver.Current
           .GetService<ISecurityService>()
           .GetUserPermissions(this.Identity.Name);

    return this.Roles.Any(p => p.Name == role);
}
```

You should set your custom `Principal` in Global.asax

```
    void OnPostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // Get a reference to the current User 
        IPrincipal user = HttpContext.Current.User; 

        // If we are dealing with an authenticated forms authentication request         
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated && user.Identity.AuthenticationType == "Forms") 
        { 
            // Create custom Principal 
            var principal = new MyCustomPrincipal(user.Identity); 

            // Attach the Principal to HttpContext.User and Thread.CurrentPrincipal 
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal; 
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal; 
        }
    }
```

You can than just mark your action with appropriate `Authorise` attributes and you can use `User.IsInRole` in views to render links conditionally.

Comment: thanks. I never had to do that so I will try it out. Also, this is an intranet application (I forgot to say that it in initial post, but that does not seem to matter here). If there is a small change to the page for all users, is it best practice to add an Html helper class to disable the ActionLink to the delete page (as an example)?

Comment: If you're going to reuse this logic than `HtmlHelper` extension makes sense; if it's in one place only than it's a bit of overkill.

Comment: @Jackup Konecki, Your answer led me to a long day of research because I was unfamiliar with roles/memberships. I am using Ninject and was getting caught, but this site helped me a lot [link](https://github.com/NickKip/ASPNETCustomMembershipExample)

Answer (score 0):

A similar question and response was found here it self

[ASP.NET MVC Alternatively Rendering EditorFor Based on User Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874081/asp-net-mvc-alternatively-rendering-editorfor-based-on-user-role)

I think you approach of having a html helper to render the view is correct. if any one can suggest a better idea most welcome.

The authorize attribute in MVC has the options to provide roles. which help us to restrict the access to controller members.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx#using_authorizeattribute