# ASP.NET MVC 4 Custom Role Authorization show/hide Edit/Delete links in Views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I want to show/hide Edit/Delete links (including menu items) depending on user's authorization. I have implemented AuthorizeAttribute and have custom logic for Roles checking in overriden AuthorizeCore. I would like to use that logic when checking whether user has permissions to view edit/delete links inside the LinkExtensions method.
This is my setup:

```
public class AuthorizeActivity : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        string actionType = httpContext.Request.HttpMethod;

        string controller = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        string action = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

        //ADMINS
        if (controller == "Admin")
        {
            if (httpContext.User.IsInRole(Constants.Admin))
                return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //DATA READERS ONLY
            if ((action == "Details") || (action == "Index"))
            {
                if (httpContext.User.IsInRole(Constants.DataReader))
                    return true;
            }
            //DATA WRITERS & IT
            else
            {
              ...
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Also I used Vivien Chevallier's logic for creating authorized action link extension outlined here: http://vivien-chevallier.com/Articles/create-an-authorized-action-link-extension-for-aspnet-mvc-3
Now in my view I can use:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLinkAuthorized("Admin", "Index", "Admin",false) </li>
```

And the link will either show up or not depending on user's rights.
In  my controller the action is decorated with:

```
    [AuthorizeActivity]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(view);
    }
```

The authorized link will not work unless I also specify 'Roles' in the attribute which I believe is redundant, like so:

```
[AuthorizeActivity(Roles = Constants.roleSalesContractAdmin)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(view);
}
```

I cant seem to find a way to reuse the logic in AuthorizeAttribute. Ideally it would be called in the ActionLinkAuthorized like Vivien's have it:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkAuthorized(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes, bool showActionLinkAsDisabled)
    {
        if (htmlHelper.ActionAuthorized(actionName, controllerName)) //The call to verify here -- or inside ActionAuthorized
        {
            return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes);
        }
        else
        {
            if (showActionLinkAsDisabled)
            {
                TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("span");
                tagBuilder.InnerHtml = linkText;
                return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is ActionAuthorized method. The OnAuthorization call does not go to the customized one

```
public static bool ActionAuthorized(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName)
    {
        ControllerBase controllerBase = string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName) ? htmlHelper.ViewContext.Controller : htmlHelper.GetControllerByName(controllerName);
        ControllerContext controllerContext = new ControllerContext(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, controllerBase);
        ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controllerContext.Controller.GetType());
        ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor = controllerDescriptor.FindAction(controllerContext, actionName);

        if (actionDescriptor == null)
            return false;
        FilterInfo filters = new FilterInfo(FilterProviders.Providers.GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor));

        AuthorizationContext authorizationContext = new AuthorizationContext(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);
        foreach (IAuthorizationFilter authorizationFilter in filters.AuthorizationFilters)
        {
            authorizationFilter.OnAuthorization(authorizationContext); //This call
            if (authorizationContext.Result != null)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You should take a look at my anwsear, could give you an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874081/asp-net-mvc-alternatively-rendering-editorfor-based-on-user-role/18874497#18874497

Comment: Why don't you extract the logic that you have in AuthorizeCore of your custom Authorization attribute into a static method, put it into some static class and reuse it both in the attribute and in the helper?

Answer (score 7):

In your view, you can write:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("role"))
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Words", "View", "Controller")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Words", "View", "Controller")</li>
}
```

... and assuming they're logged in, it will conditionally hide the links

Answer (score 1):

When you decorate an action or a controller with an authorization attribute, the action is executed only when user is authorized. This means that if the user is not authorized the view(which is going to contain all your authorized link extensions) won't be render at all.

Because of this you need to separate between authorization logic in your attribute and your logic for html extensions.

I also noticed that in authorization core of your attribute you are doing the following:

```
if ((action == "Details") || (action == "Index"))
            {
                if (httpContext.User.IsInRole(Constants.DataReader))
                    return true;
            }
```

It is **really-really bad idea**! You should not specify action names in your authorize core logic!
All you need to do is to decorate "Details" and "Index" methods with default authorize attribute that has an appropriate roles:

```
[Authorize(Roles=Constants.DataReader)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
}
```

Now regarding the role dependent helpers:

you could do something like that:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkAuthorized(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string roles, other arguments)
{
   //assuming that roles are passed as coma separated strings
   var rolesList = roles.Split(",",roles);
   bool shouldShow = false;
   foreach(var role in rolesList )
   {
       if (HttpContext.User.IsInRole(role))
       {
           shouldShow = true;
           break;
       }               
   }
   if(shouldShow)
   {
       //return your extension representation 
   }
   else
   {
       //fallback 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem
I solved this way:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class MyAuthorizedAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public bool CheckPermissions(HttpContextBase httpContext, string controller, string action)
        {
            bool authorized;

            //Validate User permissions of the way you think is best

            return authorized;
        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            var action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            var controller = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
            if (filterContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filterContext));
            }

            if (OutputCacheAttribute.IsChildActionCacheActive(filterContext))
            {
                // If a child action cache block is active, we need to fail immediately, even if authorization
                // would have succeeded. The reason is that there's no way to hook a callback to rerun
                // authorization before the fragment is served from the cache, so we can't guarantee that this
                // filter will be re-run on subsequent requests.
                throw new InvalidOperationException("AuthorizeAttribute Cannot Use Within Child Action Cache");
            }

            var skipAuthorization = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof (AllowAnonymousAttribute), true)
                                    ||
                                    filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(
                                        typeof (AllowAnonymousAttribute), true);

            if (skipAuthorization)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext) && CheckPermissions(filterContext.HttpContext, controller, action))
            {
                // ** IMPORTANT **
                // Since we're performing authorization at the action level, the authorization code runs
                // after the output caching module. In the worst case this could allow an authorized user
                // to cause the page to be cached, then an unauthorized user would later be served the
                // cached page. We work around this by telling proxies not to cache the sensitive page,
                // then we hook our custom authorization code into the caching mechanism so that we have
                // the final say on whether a page should be served from the cache.

                var cachePolicy = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
                cachePolicy.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0));
                cachePolicy.AddValidationCallback(CacheValidateHandler, null /* data */);
            }
            else
            {
                HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }

        private void CacheValidateHandler(HttpContext context, object data, ref HttpValidationStatus validationStatus)
        {
            validationStatus = OnCacheAuthorization(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Result =
                    new RedirectToRouteResult(
                        new RouteValueDictionary(new {controller = "Error", action = "Unauthorized"}));
            }
        }
    }
```

This way the logic of Vivien Chevallier worked perfectly